# No response received from the server in React Native Post API

Tags: react-native

No response received from the server in React Native Post API

- I am using vision camera۔ So this object is found while capturing the image۔
- {"height": 3264, "isRawPhoto": false, "metadata": {"Orientation": 0, "{Exif}": {"ApertureValue": 0, "BrightnessValue": 0, "ColorSpace": 1, "DateTimeDigitized": "2023:10:14 11:32:41", "DateTimeOriginal": "2023:10:14 11:32:41", "ExifVersion": "0220", "ExposureBiasValue": 0, "ExposureMode": 0, "ExposureProgram": 0, "ExposureTime": 0.03, "FNumber": 2.2, "Flash": 0, "FocalLenIn35mmFilm": 27, "FocalLength": 3.65, "ISOSpeedRatings": [Array], "LensMake": null, "LensModel": null, "LensSpecification": [Array], "MeteringMode": 2, "OffsetTime": null, "OffsetTimeDigitized": null, "OffsetTimeOriginal": null, "PixelXDimension": 1836, "PixelYDimension": 3264, "SceneType": 1, "SensingMethod": 1, "ShutterSpeedValue": 5.044, "SubjectArea": [Array], "SubsecTimeDigitized": "610", "SubsecTimeOriginal": "610", "WhiteBalance": 0}, "{TIFF}": {"DateTime": "2023:10:14 11:32:41", "Make": "vivo", "Model": "V2149", "ResolutionUnit": 2, "Software": "MediaTek Camera Application", "XResolution": 72, "YResolution": 72}}, "path": "/data/user/0/com.abcd/cache/mrousavy2897108667884643135.jpg", "width": 1836}
- 

> So the api only needs to send the path, name and type of the image۔

- So I send this
- {"name": "mrousavy2897108667884643135.jpg", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.groove/cache/mrousavy2897108667884643135.jpg", "type": "image/jpeg"}
- 
- Then it gets error
  No response received from the server in React Native Post API